# How do I install latest OpenConnect in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, openconnect

In my Ubuntu 18.04, I have OpenConnect v7.08-3 installed. But it doesn't have GlobalProtect support. OpenConnect v8.02-1 has GlobalProtect support. How can I install it in ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: ppa choices https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=openconnect : There is v7.08-3 with added GlobalProtect support https://launchpad.net/~lopin/+archive/ubuntu/openconnect-globalprotect .... and OpenConnect 8 for Ubuntu 18.04 https://launchpad.net/~phusen/+archive/ubuntu/openconnect ... etc. etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> install latest OpenConnect in Ubuntu 18.04

**OpenConnect** ppa listing : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=openconnect

There is v7.08-3 with added GlobalProtect support → https://launchpad.net/~lopin/+archive/ubuntu/openconnect-globalprotect

And OpenConnect 8 for Ubuntu 18.04 → https://launchpad.net/~phusen/+archive/ubuntu/openconnect

Comment: thank you. worked like a charm! `sudo openconnect --protocol=gp ${VPN_URL} --user=${USER}`

Comment: Thanks @pangyuteng I came here looking for pulse. This is the command I had to put if your organization/University has VPN that has to connect through Pulse Secure: sudo openconnect --protocol=pulse https://YOUR_ORGANIZATION_VPN_URL

Comment: The second option did not work for me.`ssl.CertificateError: hostname 'launchpad.net' doesn't match either of '*.internet-access.center', 'internet-access.center'`